# How to check internet data usage in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, microsoft-metro, winjs

I would like to get internet data usage from my app in **`Windows Universal Application`**

1. **WiFi data usage**
2. **Cellular Data data usage**

Currently, I'm only able to check whether internet is connected or not using **`Windows.Networking.Connectivity`**.**`NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile()`**

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkusageasync) method to get a list of the estimated data traffic and connection duration over a specified period of time, for a specific network usage state.

For an example of how these methods are used, see [How to retrieve connection usage data for a specific period of time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c9409429-7712-42e9-a2af-3940a7375c21).